# gcloud alternate ssh port connection

Tags: linux, ssh, port, gcloud

I'm just getting started with `gcloud` vm's and trying to secure them up a bit.  If I change the ssh port, what switch/flag do I add to the `gcloud` command when using the gcloud command like this

`gcloud beta compute ssh --zone "us-east4-c" "base" --project "testproject"`

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

After checking [this GCP doc](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/ssh#--ssh-flag), you can see that you'll be able to set a custom port by adding a flag called `--ssh-flag`.

For example:

```
gcloud compute ssh example-instance --zone=us-central1-a --project=project-id --ssh-flag="-p 8000"
```

It is also applicable for `gcloud beta`:

```
gcloud beta compute ssh example-instance --zone=us-central1-a --project=project-id --ssh-flag="-p 8000"
```

The sample commands will SSH to your Compute Engine instance on port 8000.

> **Note:** Before connecting, make sure you have an ingress [Firewall Rule](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/configuring-firewall) that accepts TCP on the port you've chosen.

---

**UPDATE**: If above is not working and you are getting connection refused, it means you need to configure your VM to listen to the port you wanted. Here are the steps:

1. Go to sshd configuration file : `sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config`
2. Add your chosen port for example:
   [image]
3. Save the file.
4. Restart sshd service : `sudo systemctl reload sshd.service`

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that flag also and it always rejects it.

Comment: @DonGeek-Dom I've updated my answer. Let me know if it works for you or not.